# Javascript: initialize variable outside function and use inside function

Tags: javascript, global-variables

This is my javascript code

```
var helper = document.getElementById("helper");

helper.style.position = "relative";
helper.style.width = "50px";
helper.style.height = "50px";
helper.style.border = "1px solid #000";

function move() {
    helper.style.left = event.offsetX + "px";
    helper.style.top = event.offsetY + "px";
}
```

and my html code

```
<div id="grid" onmousemove="move()" onmousedown="down()">
    <div id="helper"></div>
</div>
```

But when I call that function nothing happens. I want that variable helper to bi global and everything pre-initialized so I don't have to initialize everything all over again when function is called

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as \`getElementById\` not find the element?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14028959/why-does-jquery-or-a-dom-method-such-as-getelementbyid-not-find-the-element)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `move` function *does* have access to the `helper` variable. My guess is that the code you've shown is in a `script` element *above* the `helper` element on the page, and so when your `var helper = document.getElementById("helper");` line runs, the element doesn't exist yet.

Also note that your `move` handler is relying on IE-specific behavior (a global `event` object). While this behavior is also provided by some other browsers for compatibility, it's not provided by all. To make it more broadly compatible, accept `event` as an argument:

```
function move(event) {
    // ...
}
```

...and update your DOM0 handlers like so:

```
<div id="grid" onmousemove="move(event)" onmousedown="down(event)">
```

That works because the scope in which the code in an `onXYZ` handler is called always has an `event` symbol, even if there isn't a global one.

Or, of course, use `addEventListener` (`attachEvent` on older IE versions).

Comment: one more question. Look this http://jsfiddle.net/KkqX2/
Why is it always "reloading" and when I move my mouse it follows it but it kinda restart and showing that small div at up-left corner